# jquery button change icon with onclick

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form name="armdisarmform" action="/cameras" method="POST">
    <input type='hidden' name='armdisarmvalue' value="ENABLED"/>
    <button class="armdisarm" name="armdisarmbutton" onClick='changeicon(this, "Disarm")'>Disarm</button>
</form>
```

The values are populated from the server:

```
<form name="armdisarmform" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="POST">
    <input type='hidden' name='armdisarmvalue' value="<?php echo $userstatus; ?>"/>
    <button class="armdisarm" name="armdisarmbutton" onClick='changeicon(this, "<?php echo $armdisarm; ?>")'><?php echo $armdisarm; ?></button>
</form>
```

Essentially I have a button that changes its name to either "Arm" or "Disarm" based on the server records or when someone clicks it.  I wanted to add the unlock/lock icons from the jquery button.  So this works:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".armdisarm" ).button({
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-locked"
        }
    });

});
```

But when I pass this through a function hoping to change the icons it doesn't work:

```
var changeicon = function(t, armdisarm)
{
    if (armdisarm == "Disarm")
    {
        $( ".armdisarm" ).button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-unlocked"
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $( ".armdisarm" ).button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-locked"
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Is this not possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about doing it this way: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VB9SQ/)**.

jQuery:

```
$(".armdisarm").button({
    icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-locked"
    }
});
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).data('state', ($(this).data('state') == 'disarm') ? 'arm' : 'disarm');
    $(".armdisarm").button({
        icons: {
            primary: ($(this).data('state') == "disarm") ? "ui-icon-unlocked" : "ui-icon-locked"
        }
    });
});​
```

By using jQuery's [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function to maintain the state (disarm/arm) you can toggle the icon easily.

Comment: thanks, however my problem is that I need to go to the server to find if their settings are armed or disarmed. So when I click the button I end up refreshing the page (no ajax implementation).  With this example I always get the locked button icon.

Comment: Couldn't you change the button and state when you get the data from the server?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be due to calling your function via an inline handler:

```
<button class="armdisarm" name="armdisarmbutton" onClick='changeicon(this, "Disarm")'>Disarm</button>
```

You likely have defined `changeicon` outside of the global scope, such as in a `$document.ready()` block.  Using inline handlers is bad practice anyway.  You are best off attaching your handlers in your javacsript code block.  If your object are populated dynamically, use `.on()` to delegate your handler to a parent object (such as `body`).

With a little extra CSS, you can also change your icon/text with a couple of `toggleClass` calls:

HTML:

```
<button class="armdisarm" name="armdisarmbutton">
    <span class="disarm">Disarm</span>
    <span class="arm">Arm</span>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.arm {
   display: none;  
}
.disarmed .arm {
   display: inline;   
}
.disarmed .disarm {
   display: none;   
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("body").on('click', ".armdisarm", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('disarmed')
        .find('.ui-button-icon-primary')
        .toggleClass("ui-icon-locked ui-icon-unlocked");
    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/GPKrP/

If you want to "hack" a little more, you can do this with a single `toggleClass`:

CSS:

```
.arm {
   display: none;   
}
.disarmed .arm {
   display: inline;   
}
.disarmed .disarm {
   display: none;   
}
.disarmed .ui-button-icon-primary {
    background-position: -208px -96px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("body").on('click', ".armdisarm", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('disarmed');
    return false;
});
```

In your PHP, just add class `disarmed` to your button if it is disarmed.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/GPKrP/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you really are using the jquery-ui button class you could make use of the option method:

```
$(".armdisarm").button({icon: "ui-icon-locked" })
.on("click", function() {
    var state = ($(this).data('state') == 'disarm') ? 'arm' : 'disarm';
    $(this).data('state', state);
    $(this).button("options", "icon", (state == "disarm") ? "ui-icon-unlocked" : "ui-icon-locked");
    });
});​
```

(Using jQuery UI 1.12 here which changes `{icons: {primary: "ui-icon-locked" }}` to `{icon: "ui-icon-locked" }`)